# Heroku deploy SOAPUI mock war using heroku-cli-deploy plugin fails

Tags: heroku

I have a war generated out of SOAPUI with a mockservice. I would like to have this war deployed on a heroku tomcat container.

I followed the steps defined in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-cli

When I execute the command

```
heroku deploy:war /myPath/testv2.war --app dynamicSoapMock
```

I get the below response

```
Uploading testv2.war
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: dynamicSoapMock
       - including: webapp-runner.jar
       - including: testv2.war
 ▸    1
```

And then it returns to command prompt. Can anyone please guide me how to figure out why it fails?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Nope. I moved to AWS.